# Why am I seeing an ARC issue saying I did declare a method with a particular selector?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, automatic-ref-counting

Guess it's a simple question, but after googling and reading in a lot of documents, i'm still stuck with a stupid error. So I guess, i have some understnding problems according to ARC ...

I'm trying to write my first Objective-C Program using the new ARC-Features.
As I'm used to, i created two objects and try to call a method in the one object out of the other. I did this in old Xcode thousand times that way, but with ARC, it throws errors on me:

```
//ClassOne.h
@interface ClassOne : SPSprite 
{
    SPImage *stammImg;    
}   
-(void)methodToCall:(NSString*)msgString;   
@end

//ClassOne.m
-(void)methodToCall:(NSString*)msgString
{
   NSLog(@"called, thank you");
}

//ClassTwo.h
#import "ClassOne.h"

// somewhere in ClassTwo.m
ClassOne *myObject = [[ClassOne alloc] init];
[myObject methodToCall:@"hello"];
```

Easy, isn't it? But it doesn't work at all! What has changed in Method-Definition and Calling when making a new Project using ARC?

Compiler throws the Error:

**Automatic Reference Counting Issue:
error: receiver type 'SPSprite' for instance message does not declare a method with selector 'methodToCall:' [4]**

***Edit: Checked all the inputs about SPSprite or Upper-Case. All right.
Guess what: If I deactivate ARC in build-settings, everything works fine...***

Guess will be easy to answer for someone already coding using ARC...

Comment: Your code as shown does not in fact reflect the problem you are having, since it does not involve a class SPSprite. If you want help with your actual problem, it would be better to show your actual code.

Comment: His problem is merely the upper/lower-case typo in `[[classOne alloc] init]`. That fixed the code will work just fine, given SPSprite exists as @matt points out.

Comment: SPSPrite is a class of the sparrow-framework i'm using for my games... my ClassOne is only subclassing it. Guess it shouldn't matter since i didnt do any changes to it?

Answer (score 3):

Nothing has changed in Method-Definition and Calling when making a new Project using ARC?

The problem in your test is probably `SPSprite`. If I change `SPSprite` to `NSObject` the code compiles and runs fine.

ARC relies on naming conventions. Although it makes no difference in this example naming conventions are that class names start with an upper case letter so `classOne` would be better as `ClassOne`.

Test:

```
@interface ClassOne : NSObject {
    NSObject *stammImg;
}

-(void)methodToCall:(NSString*)msgString;
@end

@implementation ClassOne
-(void)methodToCall:(NSString*)msgString {
    NSLog(@"called, thank you");
}
@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    ClassOne *myObject = [[ClassOne alloc] init];
    [myObject methodToCall:@"hello"];

    return YES;
}
```

NSLog output:

```
called, thank you
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunatly, I'm still stuck; I rechecked the Case-Sensitive-Naming - all Classes are starting with UpperCase, so that's not the point. I even changed the Sub-Classing to a normal NSObject; Of course, that can't be the solution at all, cause my Object has to be an SPSprite (which, besides, is defined as : NSObject) to do his job, a nsobject won't be useful here. It doesn't seem to work when defined as nsobject (and commented all sprite-related code) at all, too.

Comment: You should change your example to match your suggestion of using upper-case names, not the other way around. ;)

Comment: @skywise Yes you need `SPSprite` and the problem is in that class, that is where you need to look.

Comment: @CocoaFu: in SPSprite, there shouldn't be the method i have to call; my ClassTwo is only subclassing spsprite, my methodToCall:(NSString*)str is in ClassOne...

Comment: Here is the simple logic argument: If `SPSprite` is replaced with `NSObject` the code compiles and runs. Therefore the problem is with `SPSprite`. Perhaps the `SPSprite` framework is not ARC compatible. At this point it might be best to create another question concerning using the `SPSprite` framework in an ARC project.